# How to detect a memory leak in FreeRTOS

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, freertos

I'm using a FreeRTOS V9 on an EFM32gg board and a gcc compiler, to develop my first embedded application :)
I want just to know how I can detect a memory leak in my application (basic one), is there any techniques or algorithms to do that?

Comment: Careful programming is the best technique. Then, if you have a specific problem, you use a specific approach. And.. apparently, if you don't use dynamic allocation, you won't get any memory leaks.

Comment: Thx for your fast response @EugeneSh. but I thought that using dynamic allocation will prevent me to fail in a memory leak problem because the OS will be responsible to manage the memory for me according to its heap scheme. and I want to know what approaches can I use to detect the memory leak.

Comment: dynamic memory is using `malloc`. You are responsible for calling `free` for each call to `malloc`. I'm not familiar with freertos, but a tool like Valgrind can detect memory leaks if it's available on your platform. Alternately, just make sure your number of `malloc` calls are equal to the number of `free`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FreeRTOS will not leak memory, but your application might, so you can detect it the same way you would in a non FreeRTOS application.

Memory allocation uses calls to pvPortMalloc() and vPortFree(), rather than malloc() and free() directly (http://www.freertos.org/a00111.html), and calls to those functions can be tracked in the trace tool (http://www.freertos.org/trace), or just by defining the relevant trace macros, which is how the trace tool does it (http://www.freertos.org/rtos-trace-macros.html).

Comment: Worth noting that there's also the option to use static allocation now. Thanks for that!